# Teradata - YEARFRAC equivalence

Tags: sql, teradata

I am having a hard time trying to find something that would be equivalent to YEARFRAC (Excel) for Teradata. I messed around with the below, but want I want it to display the fraction of the year. So instead of 37 I would want to see 37.033.  If possible would like it to account for leap years so wouldn't want to just divide it by 365.  Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
SELECT  (CURRENT_DATE - CAST('1985-05-01' AS DATE)) YEAR
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no direct function to get the desired output.
Excel YEARFRAC method uses different logic to calculate the output based on the optional parameter basis.

> Syntax YEARFRAC(start_date, end_date, [basis])

Considering the basis parameter as 0 or omitted, you can achieve it in Teradata using below query.

```
SELECT 
DATE'2022-05-13' AS Till_Date
,DATE'1985-05-01'  AS From_Date
,(Till_Date - From_Date)  YEAR TO MONTH AS Year_To_Month
,EXTRACT(YEAR FROM Year_To_Month)
        +EXTRACT(MONTH FROM Year_To_Month)*30.0000/360
        +( EXTRACT(DAY FROM Till_Date)-EXTRACT(DAY FROM From_Date))*1.0000/360 AS YEARFRAC
```

[image: Output]

The basis parameter with 0 or omitted uses a 30/360 format to calculate the difference.
You can find more details about the YEARFRAC logic in below link.

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/yearfrac-function-3844141e-c76d-4143-82b6-208454ddc6a8

Comment: Sorry, I thought I replied awhile ago.  This helped a ton.  Thank you so much for taking the time to help out a strange.  Really appreciate it!